# How to add favicon into Nextjs 13.5? Should i use Metadata Config or an Image file (How does they differ)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I can define a favicon in the root of the [app directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons) `app/favicon.ico` or using the Metadata API from nextjs.

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "My title",
  description:
    "My description",
  icons: {
    icon: "/assets/images/site-logo.svg",
  },
};
```

Do they both work the same? So can I choose either option, or if I configure the favicon in both ways, how does that impact it?

Comment: I idea, you choose app/favicon.ico , Personally, I easily update it in the project folder ::)

Comment: So are you saying both works the same. i wanted to know if it helps in SERPs when i use the icons property; like showing the logo along with the taget title and meta description. @skipperhoa